# Error while running apex://ContactsController : usmap notdefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am using a static resource called usmap.js and I have a controller class called contactsController. Whenever I am calling this component on SF1 platform it gives me this error.I am not able to understand its root cause as it gives this error only for the first time when I open this component through a tab then it goes way. Any workarounds for this?

---

```
<aura:component controller="ContactsController1" implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <!--Attribute Start-->
    <aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="FieldsToDisplay" type="String" default=""/>
    <aura:attribute name="myBool2" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
    <aura:attribute name="strObjName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="strFieldName" type="String" />
    <aura:attribute name="Count" type="Integer[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="SobjectRecords" type="Sobject[]"/>
    <aura:attribute name="StateName" type="String"/> 
    <!--Attribute End-->

    <!--Event handling to get State Wise Contacts - Start-->
    <aura:registerEvent name="GetStateData" type="c:GetStateData"/>
    <aura:handler name="GetStateData" action="{!c.getCons}"/>
    <!--Event handling to get State Wise Contacts - End-->

    <!--Loading static resources - Start-->

    <ltng:require styles="/resource/BootstrapCss" scripts=" /resource/jQuery, /resource/raphael, /resource/usmap" />
    <!--Loading static resources - End-->
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.performInit}"/>

</aura:component>
```

---

```
public with sharing class ContactsController1
{
    private Map<String,Schema.SObjectField> fieldMap = new Map<String,Schema.SObjectField>();
    public static List<SelectOption> fieldOption;   
    public  static Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> mapField = Schema.SObjectType.Contact.fields.getMap();
    public static map<String,String> map_AbbreviationToStateName = new map<String,String>{ 'AL'=>'Alabama',
                                                                                                'AK'=>'Alaska',
                                                                                                'AZ'=>'Arizona',
                                                                                                'AR'=>'Arkansas',

                                                                                             };


        map<String,Integer> mapStrState_intCount = new map<String,Integer>();
        Set<String> setStates = new Set<String>();

        setStates.addAll(map_AbbreviationToStateName.values());

        for(Sobject objSobject : getAllSobjectRecords(strField, strObj, strFieldsToDisplay))
        {
                if(map_AbbreviationToStateName.containsKey(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField))))
                {
                    if(!mapStrState_intCount.containsKey(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField))))
                        mapStrState_intCount.put(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)) , 1 );
                    else
                    mapStrState_intCount.put(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)), mapStrState_intCount.get(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)))+1);

                }
                else if(setStates.contains(String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField))))
                {
                    for(String abbr : map_AbbreviationToStateName.keySet())
                    {
                        if(map_AbbreviationToStateName.get(abbr) == String.valueOf(objSobject.get(strField)))
                        {
                              if(!mapStrState_intCount.containsKey(abbr))
                                mapStrState_intCount.put(abbr , 1 );
                            else
                                mapStrState_intCount.put(abbr, mapStrState_intCount.get(abbr)+1);
                        }
                    }
                }

        }
        system.debug('mapStrState_intCount-----'+mapStrState_intCount);
        return mapStrState_intCount;
    }



  }
```

I have edited my question please view it once.

---

```
({
    // Your renderer method overrides go here
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {   
            var timesToCheck = 10;
            var map = function () {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    timesToCheck--;
                    if (typeof $ !== 'undefined') {
                        console.log($);
                    } else if (timesToCheck > 0) {
                        map();
                    } else {
                        console.log('giving up')
                    }
                }, 100);
            };

            map();
        }
})
```

Comment: Post some code man!

Comment: Probably not related to the controller at all right? You could create a new component, just add the ltng:require tag and you'd still get the error I assume. In that case isn't your static resource the issue? Can you load it sufficiently in visualforce?

Comment: Yes its something like for the first time the usmap. js script takes a little more time to load then the other files so might be some issue appears and after that the issue doesn't appears.

Comment: @KrisGray I also used a rerender so as to delay it by setting out some  time function.But,it didn't help me.

Comment: Makes sense, I haven't fully debugged this area, but it makes sense the scripts are async and won't necessarily be present when your component does its work. I'll post the standard solution in answers, hopefully that works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Better answer.

You can add a controller action to the ltng:require tag that is fired when all the scripts have been loaded.

Example

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/resourceName"
    afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterScriptsLoaded}" />
```

See Documentation Here
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/lightning/Content/js_libs_platform.htm

Comment: Correct - ltng:require works with the Aura/Lightning Components lifecycle to insure that the timing is always reliable w/out resorting to setTimeouts, polling etc. ltng:require also happens to be the only Salesforce Security approved mechanism for loading javascript and css from static resources. Any other mechanism (including requirejs) will be rejected by that group's security audit process.

Comment: Learn something new every day...

Answer (score 0):

**note don't do this. It won't work. Leaving for an example of what not to do.**

When dealing with Async scripts, you'll want to use a callback to execute when your code is available.

The VERY VERY quick and dirty solution.

```
window.myCallback = function() {
// Your script is available now.
};
```

in usmap.js

```
if(typeof window.myCallback == "function") { window.myCallback(); }
```

To use a better method, check out something like RequireJs.
http://requirejs.org/

Comment: Components must not pollute the window namespace. They are components. You don't know which other components are also loaded, nor do you have permission to modify any DOM objects outside of your component. Please do not use requirejs -- use ltng:require

Comment: Right. I forget you guys are under a lot of restrictions. I need to look at ltng:require see what the proper usage is here.

Comment: @kris gray please provide a solution for that I am eagerly waiting for a solution within 1-2 days it would really be very helpful for me.

Comment: Working on it. :)